# type casting integer to void*

Tags: c, linux, pointers, pthreads, void-pointers

```
#include <stdio.h>
void pass(void* );
int main()
{
    int x;
    x = 10;
    pass((void*)x);
    return 0;
}
void pass(void* x)
{
   int y = (int)x;
   printf("%d\n", y);
}


output: 10
```

my questions from the above code..

1. what happens when we typecast normal variable to void* or any pointer variable?
2. We have to pass address of the variable to the function because in function definition argument is pointer variable. But this code pass the normal variable ..

This format is followed in linux pthread programming... I am an entry level C programmer. I am compiling this program in linux gcc compiler..

Comment: "what happen when typcating normal variable to void* or any pointer variable?" Implementation-dependent. Note that it's not guaranteed that casting an `int` to `void*` and back yields the original value (though usually, it does).

Comment: What are you actually trying to achieve?

Comment: Generally this kind of type casting does not lead to any concern as long as the addresses are encoded using the same length as the "variable type" (`int` in your case). But @DanielFischer is right the risk is that you would lose some information if the storage capacity of your variable is less than the address length. Thus, something like `void *ptr1 = a_pointer(); char ptr_c = (char)ptr1; void *ptr2 = (void*)ptr_c;` would lead to the assertion `ptr1 != ptr2`

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I'm only guessing here, but I think what you are supposed to do is actually pass the *address* of the variable to the function. You use the address-of operator `&` to do that

```
int x = 10;
void *pointer = &x;
```

And in the function you get the value of the pointer by using the dereference operator `*`:

```
int y = *((int *) pointer);
```

Comment: "I think what you should do is actually pass the address of the variable to the function"  Not necessarily. If this is the data to a thread procedure, then you quite commonly want to pass by value.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan I rephrased that sentence a little.

Comment: If you are going to pass the address you typically need to exert some more control over the lifetime of the object. Usually that means the pointer is allocated with `malloc` and then destroyed by calling `free` in the thread proc. Automatic storage isn't what you need for thread proc. I know the code in Q is not for thread proc, but it's clearly mentioned as the motivation.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan, sane thread APIs wouldn't send integral data to the thread procedures, they would send pointers. Even though what you say regarding the lifetime of the object is true, integral types are too limited for a generic API.

Comment: And in this context, it is very very very common to see programmers lazily type cast the `void *` to something like `int`. Anyway, if the OP wants a paranoid scheme, he can still malloc the appropriate amount of data to pass its value using a pointer !

Comment: This also works: `int x = 10; void *pointer = &(int){ x };`

Comment: This answer does not address the original question though

Answer (score 0):

Please read [why glib](https://developer.gnome.org/glib/2.34/glib-Type-Conversion-Macros.html) provide macros for this kind of conversions, there's no need to repeat the text here. The main point is: a pointer has a platform dependent size.

Comment: On the contrary, there _is_ a need to repeat the text here. That link will sooner or later rot, turning your answer to a completely useless one. See [here](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/118582/169090) for more information.

Answer (score 0):

If you are planning to use `pthreads` and you are planning to pass the `pass` function to `pthread_create`, you have to `malloc`/`free` the arguments you are planning to use (even if the threaded function just need a single int).

Using an integer address (like `&x`) is probably wrong, indeed each modification you will execute on `x` will affect the `pass` behaviour.

Comment: You don't necessarily _have_ to. You could also keep the parameters global, or even on the stack, if it's the same function who calls `pthread_create` and `pthread_join` which is quite often the case (`main` creates threads and then joins them before exit).

Comment: @Shahbaz you could... but I will not suggest to a C newbie to use globals. As for the stack, I've written a few libraries using pthreds, thus I don't agree that what you describe "is quite often the case". But, sure, in that specific case you can pass a local variable address, **if you know what you are doing**.